# shape.MultiPolygon

Tags: yandex-maps-api

Что такое shape.MultiPolygon? Для чего он нужен? Как с ним работать? Есть ли примеры использования? Понимает ли он данные geoJSON?

Answer (score 0):

> Что такое shape.MultiPolygon?

Пиксельная фигура "Мультиполигон".

> Для чего он нужен?

Чтобы создавать пиксельные фигуры.

> Как с ним работать?

```
new ymaps.shape.MultiPolygon(pixelGeometry[, params])
```

> Есть ли примеры использования?

Вот тут есть пример использования Rectangle для мультиполигона будет примерно также https://tech.yandex.ru/maps/jsbox/2.1/placemark_hint_layout

> Понимает ли он данные geoJSON?

В чистом виде нет. Если только вытащить координаты из geoJSON и передать их shape.MultiPolygon

Comment: Спасибо )))))))

Comment: Надо понимать, то нарисовать что-то видимое с помощью него на карте всё-равно не получится. Так что действуйте так как я ответил в предыдущем вашем вопросе.